# Python3 Function returning only first values

Tags: python-3.x, function, argparse

I'm trying to make a function that opens a textfile, counts the words and then returns the top 7 words in percent. However when I run the code with "return" it only retrieves the first value but "print" gives me what I need + a "None".

```
def count_wfrequency(fname):
    with open(fname,"r") as f:
        dictionary = dict()
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            delaorden = line.split()
            for word in delaorden:
                dictionary[word] = dictionary.get(word,0) + 1

        tmp = list()
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            tmp.append((value, key))
            tmp.sort(reverse=True)

        for value, key in tmp[:7]:
            b = ("{0:.0f}%".format(value / len(tmp)* 100))

            print(key, b, end=", ")


the 9%, to 6%, of 5%, and 4%, in 3%, a 3%, would 2%, Frequency of words: None
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: To clarify, I want to make it so that it prints out "Frequency of words: the 9%, to 6%...and so on.

Trying to use the function like this:

```
if args.word_frequency:
        print("Frequency of words: {}".format(funk.count_wfrequency(args.filename)))
```

Comment: Show how you returned from the function and how you attempted to use that return value.

Comment: Does adding `print("Frequency of words: ", end="")` before the last `for` loop not give the desired output format?

Comment: I tried this but it did not work for me. Maybe I put it in the wrong order, could you show me?

Comment: If you are only going to use the return value of the function to `print()` it, you should just do `print()` inside the function. Add the code from my previous comment above `for value, key in tmp[:7]:`. Call the function without `print()`.

Comment: Oh! Now it worked, thank you so much!